# Can we vectorize any function on pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

Assume that we have a pandas dataframe and we want to do a calculation using some columns of this dataframe and one additional data structure and fill a new column to this dataframe.

Can we do this in a vectorized way instead of using apply method:

```
snps_df['Context'] = snps_df.apply(getMutationInformation,hg19_genome=hg19_genome,axis=1)

def getMutationInformation(row,hg19_genome):
    return get3Nucleotides(row['Chrom'], row['Start'], row['Start'], hg19_genome)
```

Comment: Can you provide sample inputs and the corresponding output you'd expect?

Comment: No, you cannot vectorize every function

Comment: @smj For given chr1, 2000000, hg19 you want to get 'ACG' which is three nucleotides centered at chr1,  2000000

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga which functions can be vectorized and which function not?

Comment: In get3Nucleotides method can I do something like this in a vectorized way? hg19_genome[snps_df['Chrom']].get_slice(snps_df['Start']-2, snps_df['Start'] + 1)

Comment: Is there good information source for which functions can be vectorized and which functions can not be vectorized?